# Sorting and searching a single table inheritance structure with Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I've implemented single table inheritance using Eloquent models and now I want to be able to sort and search the database based on the parent model and the child model. I've used [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) to accomplish this.

The base model only has the morphing method.

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function extended()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

All models that extends the item has some basic properties

```
abstract class ExtendedItem extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relationships to always load with the model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['item'];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['title'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['item'];

    public function getTitleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->item->title;
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Item', 'extended');
    }
}
```

Example child classes

```
class Foo extends ExtendedItem
{
    public function bars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bar')->orderBy('bar_col1')->orderBy('bar_col2');
    }
}

class Bar extends ExtendedItem
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Foo');
    }
}
```

If I want to list all the items I use `$items = Item::with('extended')->get();` and if I only want the Foo objects I use `$foos = Foo::all();`.

---

I can order a list of all items using

`$items = return Item::with('extended')->orderBy('title')->get();`

but how can I order a list of foos by title? How can I search foos by title? Preferably this would be done on the database with a generated query and not done on an Eloquent collection.

Answer (score 0):

If following the default database structure for polymorphic relations in Laravel, I believe you can use whereHas to limit your results to only foo instances.

I don't have access to a machine to test right now, but this is what I would try:

```
$items = Item::whereHas('extended' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('extended_type', 'foo');
})->with('extended')->orderBy('title')->get();
```

Comment: I guess you mean `Item::whereHas('extended', function($q){...})->with...`. This gives me an error saying `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'self_18aab6fab05a597f53c25ac6f61ae312.id' in 'where clause' ...` with the table name changing on every refresh.

Comment: Yes indeed, that was a typo on my part. Like I said, I can't test this right now, so I'm not sure this works, but it's what I would have tried first.)

Answer (score 0):

To sort the related table, the table must first be joined.

```
return Foo::with('item')
    ->join('items', 'items.extended_id', '=', 'foos.id')
    ->orderBy('title', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Searching can be done using `whereHas`

```
return Foo::whereHas('item', function ($q) {
    $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%baz%');
})->get();
```